# Need to import a plain javascript file to react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, import

I am trying to convert HTML, CSS and JS component to react. I did quite easily with HTML and CSS but having problem with JS. I tried with react-helmet but get an error

```
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

react.js file:

```
import React,{ Component }from 'react'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import './ContactForm.css'

export default class ContactForm extends Component {
    

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <section>
                    <div className="container">
                        <form action="https://formsubmit.co/my@myemail.com" method="POST" id="my-form"> 
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label for="firstName"> First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
                                </div>
    
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label for="latsName">Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" />
                                </div>
    
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
                                </div>
    
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label for="massage">Massage</label>
                                    <textarea name="massage" id="massage" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </form>   
                    </div>
                    <div id="status"></div>
                </section>
                <Helmet>
                    <script src="./main.js"></script>
                </Helmet>
                
            </>
            
           
        )
    }
}
```

Original HTML/CSS/JS:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // get the form elements defined in your form HTML above

  var form = document.getElementById("my-form");
  // var button = document.getElementById("my-form-button");
  var status = document.getElementById("status");

  // Success and Error functions for after the form is submitted

  function success() {
    form.reset();
    status.classList.add("success");
    status.innerHTML = "Thanks!";
  }

  function error() {
    status.classList.add("error");
    status.innerHTML = "Oops! There was a problem.";
  }

  // handle the form submission event

  form.addEventListener("submit", function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(form);
    ajax(form.method, form.action, data, success, error);
  });
});

// helper function for sending an AJAX request

function ajax(method, url, data, success, error) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      success(xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
    } else {
      error(xhr.status, xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}
section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000010;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-group {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.form-group input,
.form-group textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.199);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}
button[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: rgb(27, 166, 247);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s ease background-color;
}
button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: rgb(214, 226, 236);
}
#status {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
#status.success {
  background-color: rgb(211, 250, 153);
  animation: status 4s ease forwards;
}
#status.error {
  background-color: rgb(250, 129, 92);
  color: white;
  animation: status 4s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes status {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="https://formspree.io/mbjzbwaj" method="POST" id="my-form">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName"> First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="latsName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="massage">Massage</label>
        <textarea name="massage" id="massage" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="status"></div>
</section>
```

you can find the js file in https://codepen.io/Web_Cifar/pen/gOrrPpO
I need that plain js file in react.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React is a javaScript library => you can insert JavaScript code directly into React.

```
<script src="./main.js"></script>   //--> is HTML's way to import a JS file
```

In your case, you need to format your JS code to work properly with React.

Example (with functional component and hooks):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./ContactForm.css";

export default function ContactForm() {
   const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    massage: ""
  });

  const updateFormData = (e) =>
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });

  const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);
    fetch("https://formspree.io/mbjzbwaj", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ formData }),
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const { firstName, lastName, email, massage } = formData;

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="container">
        <form id="my-form" onSubmit={submitForm}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="firstName"> First Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              value={firstName}
              onChange={(e) => updateFormData(e)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="lastName"
              name="lastName"
              value={lastName}
              onChange={(e) => updateFormData(e)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => updateFormData(e)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="massage">Massage</label>
            <textarea
              name="massage"
              id="massage"
              cols="30"
              rows="10"
              value={massage}
              onChange={(e) => updateFormData(e)}
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
     </section>
  );
}
```

Demo : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dlcgbz?file=src%2FApp.js)

---

**EDIT**

To use Formspree with React you have to use a specific hook and it's very simple ... (documentation [here](https://help.formspree.io/hc/en-us/articles/360055613373-The-Formspree-React-library))

First you need to import formspree

```
npm i @formspree/react
```

ContactForm.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from '@formspree/react';

export default function ContactForm() {
  const [state, handleSubmit] = useForm('######'); // hash id
  if (state.succeeded) {
    return <div>Sucess!</div>;
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="firstName"> First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="massage">Massage</label>
        <textarea name="massage" id="massage" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" disabled={state.submitting}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

- You will find the hash id in "form details", "integration" tab.
  in your example you had "...formspree.io/***mbjzbwaj***" (***hash id***)

Comment: Hey mate thank you, but it doesn't work. Please once try it yourself.

Comment: can you try for "https://formsubmit.co/bro@myemail.com" rather than "https://formspree.io/bro@myemail.com"  . I will also try

Comment: Yes, this is the way you would want to do it!

Comment: @axtck  thank you both. Can you check out my another recent question please, i have been stuck in these for about a week now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579675/implementing-advanced-pagination-to-my-react-site-using-react-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

In React, event handling and other functionality is done a little bit different.

You can link an event with a handler like this:

```html
<button onClick={handleClick}>CLICK</button>
```

`onClick` would be the event, and `handleClick` the handler function.

Above your render function you could make a handler like this:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  console.log("Clicked!");
  // do some functionality... 
}
```

You can also access the event by passing `(e)`

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
  console.log("Clicked!");
  // do some functionality... 
}
```

If you want to convert your code to React, I would suggest you try it out like this and checking out the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).